# Database error when trying to upload

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm transferring a website from localhost to the server. I am trying to upload the database to the one I created on my hosting account but it gives me this error:

Error
SQL query:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `nextgen`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `woof_query_cache`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `woof_query_cache` (

 `mkey` TEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
 `mvalue` TEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1046 - No database selected

I have not idea what this means or what I have to do to fix it.

Please help!!

Comment: specify the database you want to create the table in with first query : `use yourdbname;`. alternatively add the dbname prefix to the create table statement

Comment: Alternatively, login to your control panel, and if phpmyadmin is available for you, select the database then paste your code into the SQL panel. If no database exists, create one. A database and a table are not the same thing here (fyi).

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! I'm pretty new to this so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Where can I get the code?

Comment: just run `use nextgen;` before running the rest of your code. ( are you using mysql client or phpmyadmin ?

Comment: You have the code. You just need to create the database called nextgen first.

Comment: So is it giving me this error because the database is not called nextgen?

Comment: @Rixy what did you use to create this dump file?  Was it `mysqldump` or something else?

Comment: I just exported this file from the localhost database I have on phpMyAdmin

Comment: I see.  As phpMyAdmin is a rather lightweight tool, not commonly used by DBAs, I'm unfamiliar with its options.  A quick Google search suggests that if you create the database on the target server, then "select" it from the list of databases (make it the active/current database for your session) before actually importing the file, it should work.